# How find top/left and top/right of the Teechart graph and Teechart Canvas?

Tags: c++, activex, teechart

I am trying to figure out Teechart control and graph canvas of all four corners in client coordinate.

Does anyone know Teechart API that return a canvas coordinate for all four corner?

Thank you

Comment: Which TeeChart version are you interested in: VCL/FMX, .NET, ActiveX, Javascript, etc. Thanks.

Comment: We are using Teechart Pro v7.0.1.4 ActiveX (C++). I am currently support older software package.

Comment: I am also like to know if Teechart have APIs for all corner of Chart Graph itself. I would like to use this reference points to custom draw/box outside the graph.

Comment: Hello user3280398, 
Could you confirm us which IDE are you using(vc++6 or visual studio)?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 3):

To determine the position of chart in the Window Form you can use the `.Left` and `.Top` Chart properties. In the same way, you can get the `TChart` Corners using the `ChartRect`. Please take a look to the code below:

```
// CDraggingDlg message handlers

BOOL CDraggingDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
….
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    // Extra initialization
    m_ctrlChart.RemoveAllSeries();

    m_ctrlChart.GetAspect().SetView3D(false);
    m_ctrlChart.AddSeries(scLine);
    m_ctrlChart.Series(0).FillSampleValues(100); 
    return TRUE;
}

std::string text; 

void CDraggingDlg::OnAfterDrawTChart() 
{

    // Draw a white circle around the clicked pyramid...

    CTeeRect r = m_ctrlChart.GetGetChartRect();
    long recwidth, recheight, posLeft, posTop; 

    int BottomLCornerX,BottomLCornerY, BottomRCornerX, BottomRCornerY, TopLCornerX, TopLCornerY, TopRCornerX, TopRCornerY;
    std::string s1, s2, s3; 

    //Get Width
    recwidth = (r.GetRight()- r.GetLeft()); 
    recheight = (r.GetBottom()-r.GetTop()); 

    //GetPosition
    posLeft =   m_ctrlChart.GetLeft(); 
    posTop = m_ctrlChart.GetTop(); 

    //CalculateCorners
    BottomLCornerX = r.GetLeft();
    BottomLCornerY = r.GetBottom(); 
    BottomRCornerX = r.GetRight(); 
    BottomRCornerY = r.GetBottom(); 
    TopLCornerX = r.GetLeft(); 
    TopLCornerY = r.GetTop(); 
    TopRCornerX = r.GetRight; 
    TopRCornerY = r.GetTop(); 
    //Visualization Values
    s1 = "Position Chart :" + std::to_string(posLeft) + "," + std::to_string(posTop); 
    s2 = "Chart Rect Positons: Left " + std::to_string(r.GetLeft()) + " Top " + std::to_string(r.GetTop()) + " Right " + std::to_string(r.GetRight()) + " Bottom " + std::to_string(r.GetBottom());
    s3 = "Chart Rect Corners: BottomLeft  " + std::to_string(BottomLCornerX) + "," + std::to_string(BottomLCornerY) + " BottomRight " + std::to_string(BottomRCornerX) + "," +
    std::to_string(BottomRCornerY) + "\n TopLeft  " + std::to_string(TopLCornerX) + "," + std::to_string(TopLCornerY) + " TopRight " + std::to_string(TopRCornerX) + "," + std::to_string(TopRCornerY); 
    text = s1 + "\n" + s2 +"\n"+s3 ;
}
void CDraggingDlg::OnButton1()
{MessageBox(text.c_str()); }
```